# Error running GWT Stockwatcher example project

Tags: eclipse, gwt

When creating the Stockwatcher sample project in eclipse as described in the tutorial at http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/create.html, I am getting this error:

```
Unable to find 'com/google/gwt/sample/stockwatche/Stockwatcher.gwt.xml' on your classpath
```

I tried to add gwt jar files, as suggested in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/Google-Web-Toolkit/6NFBiwkxFIQ/hObZXNpIoYIJ, but it doesn't work. Any ideas as of what can be the cause/solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo in your package name. It should be `stockwatcher` not `stockwatche` (missing `r` at the end).

Comment: Thanks! In fact I didn't pay enough attention, I created the project as stockwatche instead of StockWatcher.